# A type of bodiless closure with {}()?

Tags: swift, variables, initialization

I see examples of variable initialisation code that can contain any number of statements, for example:

```
var _globalCounter = 0
let instanceCount: Int = { _globalCounter++ }()
print(instanceCount.dynamicType) // Int
```

and a full code sample:

```
struct User {
    let name: String
    let company: String
    let login: String
    let password: String        

    static let database: Dictionary<String, User> = {
        var theDatabase = Dictionary<String, User>()
        for user in [
            User(name: "John Appleseed", company: "Apple", login: "japple", password: "foo"),
            User(name: "John Hennessy", company: "Stanford", login: "hennessy", password: "foo"),
            User(name: "Bad Guy", company: "Criminals, Inc.", login: "baddie", password: "foo")
        ] {
            theDatabase[user.login] = user
        }
        return theDatabase
    }()
}
```

What's going on? Is it assignment from a closure like assigning a value from a function call?

These samples are copied form cs 193p fall 2014 class, are these considered to be good practice in terms of complex variable initialisation compared to putting stuff in init?

Please note that here in the second example the variable is static, so effectively this is a thread safe initialisation code?

I'm #learning swift and #confused.

Comment: yes, functions are named closures in swift. you can not assign it from init() because it is static

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, a closure is just a function. Like any other function, you call it by passing in the arguments inside parentheses. If it is a function that takes no arguments, then you call it with empty parentheses.

```
let one: Int = { return 1 }()
```

It's actually as simple as that :)

Comment: What's new about this is the syntax, that you are able to both define and execute a closure at variable definition statement.

Comment: Yes, it looked odd to me at first, too. Once I used it a few times, it suddenly clicked.